# Does anyone know how to resume recording in kurento media server java client?

Tags: kurento

Kurento javadocs for class org.kurento.client.RecorderEndpoint has pause method but doesn't have corresponding resume method.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `record` again when you want to resume. It works. Basically you can `pause` and `record` until you `stop` recorderEndpoint.